pre-commit-config adding local dependencies
I'm setting up pre-commit hooks on my project and I'm working with self-developped packages that happen to be in root of the project and I can't seem to add them as additional_dependencies in my config file making my pyright hook unhappy when committing in the repository. The structure is something like :
root/package1
root/package2

I would locally install them with:
cd package1
pip install package1

cd package2
pip install package2

For the pyright hook in .pre-commit-config.yaml I would have something :
 repo: https://github.com/RobertCraigie/pyright-python
    rev: v1.1.316
    hooks:
    - id: pyright
      additional_dependencies: [matplotlib, pytest, '[.package1]', '[.package2]']

But I still get some pyright errors that are from my package1 and package2 (ie relative import errors):
error: "..." is unknown import symbol (reportGeneralTypeIssues)

I wonder if there's a fix to this.

pre-commit never installs from the repository under test as it makes caching intractable (it only uses the contents of the configuration and installs in such a way that your repository is intentionally inaccessible)
requiring repository-local state usually indicates it isn't a good fit for the framework and you may be trying to do too much
that said, you can hack around this by using language: system / repo: local -- but these are the unsupported escape hatch where setting up the "correct state" for your tools is on the burden of your users rather than the framework

disclaimer: I wrote pre-commit

Thanks for the reply, I'll try out the language: system / repo: local hack, would you happen to know where I could find more on that ?. One workaround that I thought about was to add my package on pip and then add them as additional_dependencies which I think would work !

the docs show examples of both of those

In order to resolve pyright issues for my pre-commit hooks, I added this in my pre-commit-config.yml :
- repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: install-local-package
        name: Install Local Package
        entry: pip install path/to/package
        language: system
        pass_filenames: false
        always_run: true

